# How to pass multiple parameters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In project I want to pass variables such as id and model_type from template to view through an onclick function like:

```
                                                    
<div class="menu-item px-3">
   <a onclick="confirmalertApprove({{assets.id}}, {{assets.modal_type}})" class="menu-link px-3">Approve</a>            
</div>
```

and

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    
    function confirmalertApprove(id, model) {
        var assets_id = id;
        var modal_type= model;
        .........

                window.location.href = "{% url 'pending_assets_approval_view'  0, 1 %}".replace('0', assets_id).replace('1', modal_type);
                ..........
                )
            }
        })
    }
```

the above methode produce an error like:

[image]

I am a beginer in javascript. I do not know how to eliminate the error, is there any other way to transfer values ​​instead

" window.location.href = "{% url 'pending_assets_approval_view'  0, 1 %}".replace('0', assets_id).replace('1', modal_type);"

please give me a help to overcome this problem.

Comment: You *can and should* remove all the code in your question and only keep the one which is actually related to it - `window.location.href = "{% url 'pending_assets_approval_view'  0, 1 %}".replace('0', assets_id).replace('1', modal_type)` *(and please replace the variables with strings to simplify it)*

Comment: Please post code instead of images where possible.

Comment: Error messages are shown in the image, and the code in description.

Comment: is there any other way to pass data through "window.location.href"

Comment: Is the `"{% url 'pending_assets_approval_view'  0, 1 %}"` part parsed/replaced by python ? If so the question is [tag:python] related. And client javascript will run after the server-side python does.

Comment: yes, the question is python related